# Description of 7 Deadly Sins

Tags: story-identification

I recall a few years ago I read the Canterbury Tales, and I believe at some point Chaucer described what a person with each sin looks like.

I did a google search, but it does not bring up the passage. Perhaps I'm thinking of someone else?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe [The Parson's Tale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Parson%27s_Tale)? "The second part about confession is illustrated by referring to the Seven Deadly Sins and offering remedies against them." Additionally, "The Parson's Tale seems, from the evidence of its prologue, to have been intended as the final tale of Geoffrey Chaucer's poetic cycle The Canterbury Tales." So it seems it perhaps wasn't actually part of them, but may have been intended to be.

Comment: I recall it differently, but there's something here. Thanks!

Comment: Note also that the description of the parson is the antithesis of the 7 sins; He is learned and wise, tolerant, etc.